# Pass data from view to controller via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, csv

I would like to pass some data from view to my controller and create `CSV` file from it. I have created this code in my `view`:

`Button` that generates CSV:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" id="save-csv">Save to CSV</a>
```

Rest of the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var oUrl = '<?= $this->url('application/infraplk', array()); ?>';
    var projects = JSON.stringify(<?php echo json_encode($this->projects) ?>);
    var podmiot = JSON.stringify(<?php echo json_encode($this->podmiot) ?>);

    $('#save-csv').on('click', function () {

        var podmiotCSV = $('#type-select-Podmiot').val();
        var projektCSV = $('#type-select-Projekt').val();
        var typCSV = $('#type-select-Typ').val();
        var statusCSV = $('#type-select-Status').val();
        var errorsCSV = $('#type-select-Błędy').val();
        var data = [];
        if (podmiotCSV)
            data.push(podmiotCSV);
        if (projektCSV)
            data.push(projektCSV);
        if (typCSV)
            data.push(typCSV);
        if (statusCSV)
            data.push(statusCSV);
        if (errorsCSV)
            data.push(errorsCSV);

        //alert(data.length);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'save-csv-file',
            data: data
        });
    });

</script>
```

This is my model:

```
<?php
public function getValueToSaveCsv(array $data) {
   //FOR EXAMPLE
    print_r($data[0]);
}
?>
```

And my controller:

```
<?php
public function saveCsvFileAction(array $data) {

    header("Content-Type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=infraplk.csv");
    $data = $_POST;
    $model = new \Application\Model\InfraPlk($this->getDbCbkAdapter());
    $rows = $model->getValueToSaveCsv($data);

    $fp = fopen("php://output", 'w');
    fputcsv($fp, array_keys(get_object_vars($rows[0])));

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        fputcsv($fp, get_object_vars($row));
    }

    fclose($fp);
    $result = new ViewModel(array(
    ));
    return $result->setTerminal(true);
}
?>
```

It's the first time i'm using AJAX. And really don't know what to do. Can somebody help?

Comment: your data to be sent via ajax should be an object, its array at the moment.

Comment: In the documentation i have read that `data` can be `PlainObject or String or Array`

Comment: The parameter could be array. But the data needs to be in form of object. Try this: data: {data:data}

Comment: In ajax use data: $("formname").serialize();.It's fast and simple.Also add name in input tags of the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
    $.ajax({
       type:"POST",
       url:'save-csv-file',
       data: {data: data},
       success: function(response){
           //do success action here
       }
    });
```